# Url Rewrite with dynamic categories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi guys I need help from all you brilliant people .
I am creating a shopping website I am stuck while rewriting a url for product categories what I want to do is rewrite the url for categories for eg.

www.mysite.com/mens/

www.mysite.com/womens

These are main categories in my database
What I am doing right now is 
www.mysite.com/mens.php
www.mysite.com/womens.php
For rewriting my url I have to create a php page physically in directory to work 
So what now I want the url as same as

www.mysite.com/mens

www.mysite.com/womens

But I don't want to create the 
" mens.php,womens.php " page physically in the directory instead I want to make a master page that load all data for the all categories and show it as url whatever category is clicked as

www.mysite.com/mens

www.mysite.com/womens

And Same for the subcategories scenario

Answer (score 1):

Create .htaccess file in root directory and copy paste following text in it and try

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: not working i tried this many time replacing mutiple times ,
My url rewrite code is : RewriteRule ^mens/([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ mens.php?id=$1 [QSA] I get this 
http://localhost:8080/site/mens/mensclothing as i have mens.php phsically available in my site directory but iv want to make this dynamic

Comment: can you share it

Comment: <code>
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^product_specs/([0-9]*)$ product_specs.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^mens/([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ mens.php?id=$1 [QSA]
</code>

Comment: remove everything and copy past the code I submitted above and check

Comment: Now i am not able to load product details page, the page is loading but not fetching data on http://localhost:8080/gf2/product_specs/13.
Also with the page no data fetching on http://localhost:8080/gf2/mens/mensclothing
##Error on this page -http://localhost:8080/gf2/mens(this is my main category) ##

Comment: are you using CodeIgniter

Comment: try to remove .php from mens.php, (last line) your original htaccess

Comment: No I am Using php only, i have my original .htaccess

Comment: by the way men itself is a plural you does need to use mens :)

Answer (score 0):

I would trap the 2 main categories and route all subcategories to same page show-categ.php. You could actually route all requests via one single script, but I do not know anything about the rest of the website. show-categ.php could check subcat in a database ... , I suspect you are showing data driven content.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/?mens/(.+?)/$ /app/show-categ.php?cat=mens&subcat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?womens/(.+?)/$ /app/show-categ.php?cat=womens&subcat=$1 [QSA,L]
```